# Sharing viewmodel to multiple views using Caliburn.Micro in WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7, mvvm, viewmodel, caliburn.micro, caliburn

I am currently working on a project which requires multiple views of the same viewmodel. Let me describe this way:

- ViewModel: CustomerDetailsViewModel.cs (inherited from Screen class)
- View: CustomerDetails.cs (this view has CustomerDetailsViewModel as datacontext and this set automatically by Caliburn.Micro)
- View: CustomerInfo.cs (now this is the view where I want to share CustomerDetailsViewModel, which could have some data already modifed via CustomerDetails view)

I am currently using NavigationService to navigate to CustomerInfo view. Is there any way to pass the reference of current viewmodel to the view which user is navigating to in caliburn.micro?

Thanks in advance

idev

Answer (score 2):

Use the attached property cal:Bind.Model="{Binding}" to bind the view to the view model.
See http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=All%20About%20Actions "View First" section.

Alternatively you can also look into the cal:View.Context="MyContext" attached property as described here: http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Screens%2c%20Conductors%20and%20Composition "**Multiple Views over the Same ViewModel**" section.

Answer (score 1):

Add a property or two to your App.xaml.cs. What ever you put in here will persist throughout the lifetime of the application (keep in mind that tombstoning will cause this property's value to be lost though). If you want to pass a ViewModel then setyour associated property in App.xaml.cs to the view model and then when the new page loads have it read from that same property.